# Changing color of a ul class wrapped within a specific hiearchy

Tags: html, css, django, web, styling

```
<div class="one"> 
    <nav id="sidebar" class="col-md-auto col-lg-2 d-md-inlineblock fontsize-5rem text-white sidebar">
        <div class="position-sticky">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="{% url 'dashboard:dashboard' %}" class="nav-link active">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
```

I am trying to figure out how to customize the background of  wrapped within a specific hierarchy. I want to specifically change the color of nav-link active class here. How do I go about it? Is there any issue with any declaration here and the way it is framed? I confess that I do not know much about html except what I have gathered from Dash module in python.
If possible, please also suggest me a way to go around managing the page structure of Django Dash wherein how do I configure the page setup if I am uploading Django dash set up directly in html template?
Thank you!

Color does not change. If other items on vertical tabs get selected, they change color but not the main first tab.

Comment: This is a question about CSS but doesn't show the CSS in use, use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being set and from where. Are you saying that .nav-link.active as a CSS selector is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to give your `<ul>` tag an id.

Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #ul-nav li .active { 
      background-color: yellow;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one"> 
    <nav id="sidebar" class="col-md-auto col-lg-2 d-md-inlineblock fontsize-5rem text-white sidebar">
        <div class="position-sticky">
            <ul class="nav flex-column" id="ul-nav">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a href="{% url 'dashboard:dashboard' %}" class="nav-link active">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
     </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Explanation:
[image: Explanation]